# Make data from factory http.get accessible to entire controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, http-get, angularjs-factory

I am trying to give access to a json file that contains config information for my project (things like rev number, project name, primary contact, etc) I created a factory that retrieves the json file using http.get, I can then pull that data into my controller but I am unable to access it from anywhere in the controller.

I did not write the factory, I found it as an answer to another person's question and it is copied almost entirely so if it not the right way to accomplish what I am trying to do please correct me.

here is the factory:

```
app.factory('configFactory', ["$http", function($http) {

    var configFactory = {
        async: function() {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            var promise = $http.get('assets/json/config.json').then(function(response) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                console.log(response.data.config);
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response.data.config;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return configFactory;

}]);
```

and here is my controller:

```
app.controller('footerController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'configFactory', function footerController($scope, $rootScope, configFactory) {
    var body = angular.element(window.document.body);
    $scope.onChange = function(state) {
        body.toggleClass('light');
    };
    configFactory.async().then(function(d) {
        $scope.data = d;
        // this console log prints out the data that I am trying to access
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
    // this one prints out undefined
    console.log($scope.data);
}]);
```

So essentially I have access to the data within the function used to retrieve it but not outside of that. I can solve this with rootScope but I am trying to avoid that because I think its a bandaid and not a proper solution.

Any help would be great but this is my first experience with http.get and promises and all that stuff so a detailed explanation would be very much appreciated.

[**EDIT 1**] The variables from the config file will need to be manipulated within the web app, so I can't use constants.

Comment: You can't get the data outside of `then` because first `console.log` is called before the request was completed. That's how async code works.

Comment: @estus So what can I do to fix it? I can add a timeout function to give a short delay (like 10ms) but that just seems hacky.

Comment: Do everything that concerns `configFactory` inside `then` callback, it's as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign your response data to scope variable , create a property in your factory itself and assign the response to this property in your controller when your promise gets resolved.This way you will get the value in all the other controllers.

I have updated your factory and controller like below

```
app.factory('configFactory', ["$http", function($http) {

    var configFactory = {
        async: function() {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            var promise = $http.get('assets/json/config.json').then(function(response) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                console.log(response.data.config);
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response.data.config;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        },
      config:'' // new proprety added
    };
    return configFactory;

}]);

    app.controller('footerController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'configFactory', function footerController($scope, $rootScope, configFactory) {
    var body = angular.element(window.document.body);
    $scope.onChange = function(state) {
        body.toggleClass('light');
    };
    configFactory.async().then(function(d) {
       // $scope.data = d;
         configFactory.config=d;
        // this console log prints out the data that I am trying to access
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
    // this one prints out undefined
    console.log($scope.data);
}]);
```

Comment: I made the changes to my code and it runs but I still have the same problem, the console.log call on the last line returns 'undefined' this does not seem to give me access to the data outside of the function.

Comment: Mostly you don't write any logic directly in the controller's body, you most probably be having logics in some function only. So lets say if you want to use this config in some other function other than in which you have assigned it you will get it..The reason you are not getting it in your current code is because your console.log is written directly in the controller's body and is getting executed before the promise getting resolved. Put this code in some function and the call this function on some event like ng-click or something..you will get the data and will not get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using angular constants? http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/ You can leverage them as global variables accessible from any controller without the ramifications of assigning the values to `rootScope`

Comment: This would work but I do need to have change access for the variables. I will edit the question to include this.